# Simplify a boolean algebra expression to switch between values

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm a little rusty on my boolean algebra and am looking for some help.  I need to select between two values (Y & Z), based on the value of X.  If X is true, W should be equal to the value of Y.  If X is false, W should be equal to the value of Z.  Below I have an expression I think works and a truth table:

[image: Example]

I'm looking at it and am thinking this expression can be simplified to two blocks.  I'm actually writing some logic in a controller and I need to do this many times, so a cleaner expression would help.  My options for logic operators are:

- AND
- OR
- XOR
- XNOR

And I have the ability to NOT any of the inputs.  Can this be simplified?  Thanks.

Comment: This is called the '*switching term*'. If I interpret it correctly, you propose $(X\land Y) \lor(\lnot X\land Z)$. I think we can't express it any simpler.